# How to get different output from one click event in Angular with more than one component?

Tags: angular

I have no idea how to display a pop-up window with various content using the same method. I have two components - first one contains a form with some info links.

**form-component.html**

```
<a href="" (click)="openInfoPopup()">Info</a>
...
<a href="" (click)="openInfoPopup()">Info</a>
...
<a href="" (click)="openInfoPopup()">Info</a>
```

**form-component.ts**

```
openInfoPopup() {
...
let dialogRef = dialog.open(MyDialogComponent, dialogConf)
}
```

It works perfectly - `openInfoPopup()` opens my dialog as I want, but my poor knowlegde of Angular so far doesn't allow me to take the next step. Depending on which link you click, my popup should contain another text message. Clicking first link should open new dialog with first element of array below etc. In the second component, I created an array with my messages:

**my-dialog-component.ts**

```
infoArr = ["Text1", "Text2", "Text3", "Text4", "Text5", "Text6"];
```

**my-dialog-component.html**

```
<p *ngFor="let message of infoArr; let i = index"> {{ }} </p>
```

What should I do to make it work? How can I transfer data from my array to form-component and what I need to insert into **my-dialog-component.html** interpolation?

Comment: "dialog.open(MyDialogComponent" is actually what opens your dialog window, try to put other component instead. you can have few methods, each opening different popup

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do here is parameterise your `openInfoPopup()` calls. The parameter would be whatever the unique key is for the different types. I'll use a string for simplicity.

**form-component.html**

```
<a href="" (click)="openInfoPopup('type1')">Info</a>
...
<a href="" (click)="openInfoPopup('type2')">Info</a>
...
<a href="" (click)="openInfoPopup('type3')">Info</a>
```

**form-component.ts**

```
selectedType: string;

openInfoPopup(type: string): void {
  this.selectedType = type;

  // open dialog
}
```

Once you know what the source of the event is, you can pass that information to the dialog.

Edit:

You've now clarified that you're using Angular Material.

In which case, you pass the key in via the `open()` function:

```
openInfoPopup(type: string) {
  this.selectedType = type;

  const dialogConf = new MatDialogConfig();
  dialogConf.width = "480px";
  let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(MyDialogComponent, {
    width: '480px',
    data: { type: this.selectedType }
  });
}
```

From the docs, you can access injected information like this:

```
export class YourDialog {
  constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) { }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The line of code you are asking about opens my dialog. First part of  a bracket, (MyDialogComponent) refers to a component and the second one - dialogConf - is just a variable declared one line earlier containing configuration of my dialog (just it's width set at 320px)

Comment: Could you add the relevant code to your question. That might determine whether or not a suggested solution is suitable.

Comment: Everything what is inside my openInfoPopup() method is included in my question now

Comment: Ah, now I see you're using Angular Material. Can't you just pass the data in via the open call? `this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog, {
      width: '250px',
      data: {name: this.name, animal: this.animal}
    });`